# c# and SMO - Get Message output such as "Table already exists" for logging

Tags: c#, smo

I am using SQL Management objects to connect to SQL server. At the moment they contain simple "create table" commands for my example.

I run this code twice on purpose to cause an error for "table already exists".

However my events below are not getting triggered.

Anyone got any ideas, how I can get hold of this message in my code other then changing the ExecutionType to stop on errors causing exceptions ( which I dont want to do, I want to continue)

My Code:

```
public void executeSomeSQL() {
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"\c:\sqlcommands.sql");
    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
    conn.InfoMessage +=new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(conn_InfoMessage);
    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
    server.ConnectionContext.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(ConnectionContext_InfoMessage);
    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script,ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError);                
    MessageBox.Show("All Done");
}
```

Events:-

```
public void conn_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) {
    textBox3.Text += "1:"+DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

public void ConnectionContext_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) {
    textBox3.Text += "2:" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx):

> The InfoMessage event occurs when a
>   message with a severity of 10 or less
>   is returned by SQL Server. Messages
>   that have a severity between 11 and 20
>   raise an error and messages that have
>   a severity over 20 causes the
>   connection to close.

The error severity for a CreateTable on a table that already exists is 16, which bypasses the InfoMessage event.

You might want to wrap your TSQL in a Try...Catch block and use RAISEERROR.  A TRY…CATCH construct catches all execution errors with severity greater than 10 that do not terminate the database connection.

Or, you might want to add a check in your TSQL for the existence of the table and do a Print which will be raised to your InfoMessage event.

Comment: beat me to posting the exact same quote from MSDN :-D

Comment: Many thanks for your input - to get round this I split the commands via regrex and executed them individually and logged each inner exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not programmer (DBA), therefore I'm not sure.
I assume following cam be helpfull

conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.